# RavenDB v1 (888) How do I get a complete list of attachment keys?

Tags: ravendb, attachment

In RavenDB v1 (build 888), how do I get a complete list of attachment keys?  Right now the /static endpoint only shows ~30 when there are over 23k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /static endpoint has querystring parameters start  and pageSize that you can use to page through the list

Comment: My assumption is that "start" is somewhat like skip, is that correct?  Smuggler reports that my database has ~23k attachments.  Why is it that http://host/databases/dbname/static?start=500&pageSize=1000 is still reporting attachments?  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: Found the answer, the start value is the number of records to skip,